# Regex PHP -> double results

Tags: php, regex

Need to get and check for strings /get/ or /post/ only.

Following regex produce two results , but i actually need only the first one, how to correct this below regex query.

```
regex:  \/(post|get)\/

eg: http://www.google.com/get/

result:

Array
(
    [0] => /get/
    [1] => get
)
```

how to check for string `/abcdef=/` -> regex used `\/*=\/` , but it is not giving any results..

Comment: One is full set of what you searched for and the other is because you have a group and shows that as the second item

Comment: if you want to ignore the second result (capture) use a non-capture group `(?:  )` instead of `(   )`

Comment: @Class i need only the full set, how to change it?

Comment: @remus how to check for /hhjhj=/ -> i have used \/*=\/ , but it is nor working?

Comment: Try `\/\w*=\/` for that

Comment: @hjpotter92 Sorry. It is working perfectly. Superb. Many Thanks! Potter.

Comment: @hjpotter92 how to include even if the word contains special character like . or =, on those case \w is not working ??

Comment: Put `\w` inside square brackets along with all other characters you want: `\/[\w.!@]*=\/`

Answer (score 0):

You get two results because you use brackets for (get|post)
If there are no brackets in a RegExp, the result would contain only the match itself.
If there are brackets, then the 1st result will contain the global match, and each consequent result will contain the brackets content, in your case it's "get".

You just don't pay attention to $matches[1] and use $matches[0], consider the following:

```
$url = "domain.com/get/";
preg_match("/\/(post|get)\//", $url, $match);
$path = $match[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

From `http://www.google.com/get/` if you want only `get`  ,

You can use [**positive look ahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) :

```
(?<=\/)(post|get)(?=\/)
```

**[Demo and Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/bV3aE4)**

If you want to check `/abcdef=/`  you can use : `(\/.*=\/)`

**[Check Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jI6gI6)**